# Flex How to change button state in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

i can do this:

```
<s:Button id="Btn" enabled.State1="false" />
```

But the following code is giving me an error.

```
 private function enableDisable():void{
       Btn.enabled.State1="false";  //Error: Access of undefined property State1
      }
```

how to code **enabled.State1** in ActionScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not what you want to hear, but here it goes anyway: why do you want to do that? The whole purpose of the states is that you wouldn't have to write tons of ActionScript to do the same thing.

**Why you can't do it like that**

By writing `Btn.enabled.State1` in ActionScript you're essentially saying: give me the property called 'State1' of the Boolean instance called 'enabled'. Obviously that won't work because a Boolean doesn't have such a property. You're confusing the MXML dot (.) notation - used for assigning values to properties based on states - with the ActionScript dot notation - used for reading/writing properties.

**A solution** or as close as it gets

Since it's the very nature of this feature that you would use it in MXML, you can't do exactly what you're asking for in ActionScript. The next best thing would be to listen for [StateChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/StateChangeEvent.html) en set the Button's 'enabled' property according to the new state name.

```
addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE, onStateChange);

private function onStateChange(event:StateChangeEvent):void {
    switch (event.newState) {
        case "wrong":   Btn.enabled = false; break;
        case "correct": Btn.enabled = true; break;
    }
}
```

(I'm using the same states as in James' answer)

Comment: yes, i know using MXML is better but being able to use it in AS would make coding a bit more flexible. As MXML will finally translate into AS code, thus i assume there is an easy way to use it in AS. Using Event to change State could be a bit heavy. I could be wrong but thanks anyway.

Comment: @jameslcs I must admit I haven't looked at the generated AS code for this feature yet, but I assume that it does pretty much what I've written (i.e. tracking state change events and setting properties accordingly) but in a more generic way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using states in the wrong context. For instance, you have component which contains a user input with a button next to it. The button is only enabled when the correct word is input. You would define two states for the component, perhaps `correct` and `wrong`.

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="wrong" />
    <s:State name="correct" />
<s:states>
```

You would then, similar to what you've done above, set individual properties for the buttons depending on the state:

```
<s:Button id="Btn" enabled.wrong="false" enabled.correct="true" />
```

By default, the state of the component would be `wrong`. After handling user input and checking if the correct word is entered, the state of the component would be changed to `correct`.

Normally the state-specific properties of components are set at compile time and the state of the component itself changed at runtime.

Here is [an overview of states in Flex 4.6](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html)